# The mkdir command not allowing to make changes in any of its files

Tags: read-only, mkdir

I created a folder in Desktop and created some .asm files in there. Now the folder's owner is "root" and I cant change any of it's file rather than first time. It open files in "Read-Only" Mode!

Comment: `sudo chown -R user:user  foldername` (where user is your username and foldername is the name of the folder you mentioned )

Comment: Most probably you have made them using `sudo`. now you can change the ownership with `sudo` Go through @thom's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the ownership of those files back to your user.

Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```

This will change back the ownership of *all files in your home directory* back to your user. If you prefer to only modify those in the folder on your desktop, use the command below instead:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/Desktop/YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME
```

We use `sudo` to run the operation as root, which requires you to enter your account password.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently created the files as root.

You can reassign ownership of foldername to your user ("username") by

```
sudo chown -R username:username foldername
```

First navigate to your desktop in the terminal of course.

An alternative is to grant you the rw rights which could be done by:

```
sudo chmod o+rw foldername
sudo chmod o+rw foldername/*.asm
```

Again, navigate to your desktop in the terminal prior to executing the commands.

Comment: Probably the group of those files/directories is also set to root. It would be better to change both owner user and group instead of only the user.

Comment: Good point, assuming he uses Ubuntu he has his own user group as well.